# simple code notation

Tags: c++

I have never seen this notation....

> CreateProcess (L"c:\s2.exe", NULL,
>   NULL, NULL, false, 0, NULL, NULL, &s,
>   &po)

The first parameter has L"c:\s2.exe", what exactly is that L?

Thanks

Comment: IMHO there is a missing backslash here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This stands for a [wide character](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/467298-c-what-does-it-mean-when-l-preceeds-a-string-constant/) string, e.g. Unicode.

Comment: Actually this means that the string is internally represented with the basic character type `wchar_t` which roughly corresponds to UTF16 on Windows.

Comment: You were faster than me changing it. Thanks for your correction!

Answer (score 2):

The L is a prefix to indicate that the string is a `wchar_t` string.